# Cached and Filtered Aggregation Methods

Tags: caching, class-design, filtering, aggregation

I have a Polling system.  I want to be able to calculate results based on filtered subsets of votes.  To do this, I'm allowing the caller to pass a subquery to my model, which is then used to select only a subset of the votes when calculating results.

The catch is that I want to cache my results, and queries are flexible to the point of being horrible keys in a cache hash.  This is where I come to you: How should I pass filters into my result methods in order to strike the best balance between good code practice, reliable caching (i.e. the coder can easily understand when things are being cached), and filter flexibility.

**Option 1: Suck it up and live with query hashes**

pass the $voteFilter into each method so that the methods look something like this:

```
class Poll {
     getResults($voteFilter) {...} // Returns the poll results for passed filter
     getWinner($voteFilter) {...}  // Returns the winning result for passed filter
     isTie($voteFilter) {...}  // Returns tie status for passed filter
}
```

The methods would check their caches and if that filter query had been used, it just uses those results.  This is risky because you could have the same result set generated by slightly different queries (i.e. the order of a reflective logical clause is swapped).  I feel this means a coder could accidentally not be using a cache when he/she intends to.

This also feels like I'm passing a lot back and forth when I don't need to -- presumably the coder will be working with a single filter set across all of the result methods (When I want the results and the winner and the tie status, it will probably be for the same vote filter at any given moment)

**Option 2: Set the filter using a separate class method**

Pass the $voteFilter that is currently being used using a setFilter() method, starting a result session.  This would reset the cache each time it is called and would dictate the filter used in result methods until the next time setFilter is called.  Looking like this:

```
class Poll {
     setVoteFilter($voteFilter) {...} // Clears cache and sets vote filter
     getResults() {...} // Returns the poll results for current filter
     getWinner() {...}  // Returns the winning result for current filter
     isTie() {...}  // Returns tie status for current filter
}
```

This option feels more elegant and I like it, but I don't know if it is bad form and is the kind of thing I'll look at in two months and say "this is horrible.  Why would I have made methods without explicit parameters"

**Option 3: Define a more rigid filtering technique**

If I limit the ways I can filter I can create filter parameters which have no room for confusion, solving the ambiguity issues in Option 1.  This limits flexibility and could result in a less understandable API.  I like this choice least but wanted to throw it out here for consideration in case someone has a strong thought.

Anyone have insight?  Other options?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that `Poll` is immutable with a signature like:

```
class Poll {
   withFilter(filter)
   getFilter(...)
   getResults(...)
   getWinner(...)   
}
```

Now, `withFilter` returns a Poll object that has the given filter applied (perhaps cumulative, however as you note, care must be taken -- e.g. an AST or context must be handle or filter must fall into a certain class of restrictions). The object returned can be a *new* Poll object or a *cached* Poll object -- if Poll is immutable it doesn't matter. If the cache is maintained entirely with reach-ability then this may also handle "cleanup" -- but that really depends upon language.

Happy coding.